# Google App Script find text from Google Document next to key text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a PDF file saved in Google Drive, I want to find a text from that file i.e USD then pick the value next to found text i.e: 167.1764, and insert it in my google spreadsheet.

Below is the preview of my PDF File.
[Link](https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/rates/war/2021/sep/08-sep-2021.pdf) to my PDF File.
[image]

Here is the code below which I tried but failed to find the text and reached to that value which is next to it.

below is my code.

```js
function extractTextFromPDF() {

  var drive = DriveApp;
  var folders = drive.getFolderById('folderid');
  var newfile = folders.getFilesByName('08-Sep-2021.pdf');
  if(newfile.hasNext()){
    var file1 = newfile.next().getBlob();
  }
  
  var blob = file1;
  var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
  };

  // Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});

  // Extract Text from PDF file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  Logger.log(text);
  //DriveApp.getFileById(file.id).setTrashed(true);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("(USD)");

while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

    // Where in the element is the found text?
    var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
    var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
}
    // i want the value of USD i.e 167.1144 in log
    Logger.log(foundText);
  
  
}
```

Comment: Is the format of the file always the same? Could you share the actual PDF for testing?

Comment: yes, the same format, I had updated my PDF file link in the Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) you can extract this. I'm not the best with those patterns. But maybe somebody else can optimize so the split is not necessary. ([here](https://regex101.com/r/qScI6o/1) is a link).

**The code:**

```
function extractTextFromPDF() {
  const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('1QVo_pxxx387WPH9Yx');
  const newfile = folders.getFilesByName('08-Sep-2021.pdf');
  if(newfile.hasNext()){
    var file1 = newfile.next().getBlob();
  }
  
  const blob = file1;
  const resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
  };

  // Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
  const file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {convert: true});

  // Extract Text from PDF file
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  const text = doc.getBody().getText();
  Logger.log(text);
  const buying = /USD\n(.*?)$/gm.exec(text)[1].trim();
  const selling = /USD\n\s*\S*\n(.*?)$/gm.exec(text)[1].trim();
  
  console.log(buying) 
  console.log(selling)

  //Remove the converted file.
  DriveApp.getFileById(file.id).setTrashed(true);

}
```

Comment: the above script is not working, also I need buying selling for USD only.

Comment: Then you should post a real pdf. I saved your screenshot as pdf and got exactly the result you wanted..

Comment: okay, I had updated my PDF file link in the Question.

Comment: Super @RemcoE33:
Thanks a lot, I want to learn more about this "RegEx".  Can you guide me where I can? any video tutorial?

Comment: @MehdiAbbas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhzKDrUiJVk&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified